# Get AVG sales based on number of times a Unique Transaction ID occurs (SNOWFLAKE)

Tags: sql, average, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a retail DB that I want to pull my Transaction Sale AMT along with product level detail.

Unfortunately, I realized my SALE_AMT column is my total transaction sale amount rather than an itemized sale by product. Because of this, my SALE_AMT is being duplicated by the number of times that unique Transaction ID appears (based on how many products were purchased in that one transaction).

I think the best way to combat this and get an accurate Transaction Sale_AMT is to perform an AVG on SALE_AMT / Number of times that specific transaction ID occurs. However, I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do that. My SQL is below:

```
WITH PRODUCT_CTE AS (
  ...
)

SELECT
A.TRANS_UNIQUE_KEY, //Unique Transaction Identifier//
...
A.SALE_AMT, // This is the field for SALE_AMT showing the entire transaction SALE AMT and duplicated for each product
...
D.PRDCT_DESC,
...
FROM "tablename"A

LEFT OUTER JOIN "tablename"G
ON A.DT_SKEY = G.DT_SKEY

LEFT OUTER JOIN "tablename"H
ON A.TM_SKEY = H.TM_SKEY

LEFT OUTER JOIN "tablename"C
ON A.STORE_KEY = C.STORE_KEY

INNER JOIN "tablename"E
ON A.TRANS_TYP_KEY = E.TRANS_TYP_KEY

LEFT OUTER JOIN "tablename"F
ON A.CUST_KEY = F.CUST_KEY

LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_CTE D
ON A.TRANS_UNIQUE_KEY=D.TRANS_UNIQUE_KEY

WHERE YEAR(G.FISCAL_DT)>= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
ORDER BY G.FISCAL_DT DESC
```

Example of Transaction Sale Duplication by Product:
[image: Example of Transaction Sale Duplication by Product]

Comment: Sample data, desired results and a simplification of the query would all make it more likely that your question gets answered.

Comment: Maybe you want a Windowed Aggregate: `A.SALE_AMT / count(*) over (partition by A.TRANS_UNIQUE_KEY)`

Comment: @dnoeth - That's EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thanks for the tip =). made those changes and will keep in mind for the future!

Comment: the `sale_amt/count(*) over (partition by..)` will give a fake per item price, but it doesn't make sense to put a fake price of each item. If you are rolling up to a transaction, you don't want the `SUM` of the fake `AVG` parts, but more something like `ANY_VALUE`

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim If the values are all the same for the key, then AVG works and the value isn't fake.  If the values are not the same, then the value becomes incorrect, but it would for ANY_VALUE, as well.

Comment: well `plush animal` and `chair` probably don't have the same price, so have a per item price that is the average, is just wrong. But if you are going to turn back around and sum them up. you will get back to the value you already had. Unless you are suggesting that the "total" price SALE_AMT is difference across the rows in the same transaction. then that seems even more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

So you get an estimated/average/fake per item price by taking the average

```
WITH data_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Rocking Chair'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Plush Animal'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Rug'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Couch'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Bar Stool'),
        (2,'2020-01-28',59.09,'Painting'),
        (2,'2020-01-28',59.09,'Rug')
        v(trans_unique_key, fiscal_dt, sale_amt, prdct_desc)
)
SELECT a.*
    ,sum(fake_item_cost_2dp)over(partition by trans_unique_key) AS sum_of_parts_not_eqaul_the_whole
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,SALE_AMT/count(*)over(partition by trans_unique_key) as FAKE_ITEM_COST
        ,round(FAKE_ITEM_COST,2) AS fake_item_cost_2dp
    FROM data_table
) AS a
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

which gives:

```
TRANS_UNIQUE_KEY    FISCAL_DT   SALE_AMT    PRDCT_DESC  FAKE_ITEM_COST  FAKE_ITEM_COST_2DP  SUM_OF_PARTS_NOT_EQAUL_THE_WHOLE
1   2020-01-27  517.66  Rocking Chair   103.53200000    103.53  517.65
1   2020-01-27  517.66  Plush Animal    103.53200000    103.53  517.65
1   2020-01-27  517.66  Rug 103.53200000    103.53  517.65
1   2020-01-27  517.66  Couch   103.53200000    103.53  517.65
1   2020-01-27  517.66  Bar Stool   103.53200000    103.53  517.65
2   2020-01-28  59.09   Painting    29.54500000 29.55   59.10
2   2020-01-28  59.09   Rug 29.54500000 29.55   59.10
```

which is it is generally considered bad to round and sum, or average and the sum again, and/or floating point numbers are not stable.

But one of my main points is have a fake_per_item_price does not make much sense unless you are going to aggregate back up to the transaction level again, at which point would have something like just getting the `ANY_VALUE` make more sense.

```
WITH data_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Rocking Chair'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Plush Animal'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Rug'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Couch'),
        (1,'2020-01-27',517.66,'Bar Stool'),
        (2,'2020-01-28',59.09,'Painting'),
        (2,'2020-01-28',59.09,'Rug')
        v(trans_unique_key, fiscal_dt, sale_amt, prdct_desc)
)
SELECT trans_unique_key, fiscal_dt, ANY_VALUE(sale_amt) as sale_amt, count(*) as total_items_count, count(distinct prdct_desc) as distinct_items_count 
FROM data_table
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

giving:

```
TRANS_UNIQUE_KEY    FISCAL_DT   SALE_AMT    TOTAL_ITEMS_COUNT   DISTINCT_ITEMS_COUNT
1   2020-01-27  517.66  5   5
2   2020-01-28  59.09   2   2
```